# Why is it called citet and citep?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am never able to remember when to use `\citet` and when `\citep`, mostly because I always think citep=cite person (which is the opposite of the truth).
Where do the abbreviations come from?

Answer (score 7):

The [`natbib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) explains the two commands like this (p. 4)

> `\citep{jon90}` for a *parenthetical* citation (Jones et al., 1990),
>
> `\citet{jon90}` for a *textual* one, as Jones et al. (1990).

This is also the naming convention `biblatex` uses for its more verbosely named `\parencite` and `\textcite`.

APA style calls these two types *parenthetical citation* and *narrative citation* (see e.g. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/parenthetical-versus-narrative; incidentally the `apacite` package defines `\cite` for parenthetical citations and `\citeA` for narrative citations).